# Open Image from listView when item is clicked

Tags: android, sqlite, listview, android-intent, onclick

I'm doing an application which consists in a database that stores gps data, take pictures and store it in a SQLite data base displayed in a ListView like this:

---

- TIME: HH:MM:SS
- LATITUDE: 0.00
- LONGITUDE: 0.00
- ALTITUDE: 0
- IMAGE:/storage/sdcard0/..../image.jpg

---

**What I would like to do**

I would like that when a item of the list is clicked open the image related to that image path in a new activity.

---

**What do I have**

What I have got is that when a item is clicked I can get in a toast the image path of tat entry. But I'm stuck in how I can pass this string value to the new activity and use it to display it in the imageview.

This is the part of the code where I get the item data:

```
        Contact_listview.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {
        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Has seleccionado " + contact_data.get( + i).getUrl(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the following

On your method:

Add after the display of your toast:

```
//Locate and create the image
File imgFile = new  File(“contact_data.get( + i).getUrl()”);

if(imgFile.exists()){
//Create a bitmap so the ImageView can load it
String myBitmap = imgFile.getAbsolutePath();

Intent myIntent = new Intent (CurrentClass.this, NewActivity.Class);
myIntent.putExtra("imagePath", myBitmap);
startActivity(myIntent)
```

In The new activity declare an Image view and just add the following:

```
Bitmap myBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(getIntent().getStringExtras("imagePath"));

ImageView myImage = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.yourimageview);
myImage.setImageBitmap(myBitmap);
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply! I've done what you said but my imageview displays black pictures. Maybe I'm not getting the path correctly?

Comment: Thanks again! I've follow your steps but I only get a blank image in the second activity.

Comment: Are you adding the second routine this in your OnCreate method of the new activity?

Answer (score 0):

```
 Contact_listview.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {
           String imgUrl = contact_data.get( + i).getUrl();
           launchImageViewer(imgUrl);

        }
});


public void launchImageViewer(String url){
   Intent i = new Intent(this, YourImageViewActivity.class);
   i.putExtra("imageUrl", url);
   startActivity(i);
}
```

then in the `onCreate()` of your second activty look for the extra and use it:

```
String imgUrl = getIntent().getExtra("imageUrl");
```